# Networkx graph exporting to Pyvis - TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, typeerror, networkx, graph-theory, pyvis

I have a dataframe as below

```
    Quote ID    Quote Date       Email                Phone       VIN
0   1410095416  6/6/2021    DAMIONADAE@GMAIL.COM    4049366688  1C4RJFBG9EC2267
1   1410143058  6/6/2021    BEEZZZHAPPY@YAHOO.COM   3122340791  NaN
2   1408893417  6/3/2021    MONEYKAY38@YAHOO.COM    2149004015  1J8HG48NX6C2470
3   1408764243  6/2/2021    TIFFANYLESTER419@GMAIL.COM  5024647900  JN8AZ08W57W6527
4   1408639003  6/2/2021    MONEYTEAM799@YAHOO.COM  2149001015  1ZVBP8AM3E52605
```

I'm using a function to generate network graph. The below function takes the dataframe, node and edges to generate the Graph.

```
def create_network(df, node, column_edge, column_edge1=None, column_edge2=None):

    #  select columns, remove NaN
    df_edge1 = df[[node, column_edge]].dropna(subset=[column_edge]).drop_duplicates()

    # To create connections between "node" who have the same "edge",
    # join data with itself on the "node" column.
    df_edge1 = df_edge1.merge(
                              df_edge1[[node, column_edge]].rename(columns={node:node+"_2"}), 
                              on=column_edge
                              )

    # By joining the data with itself, node will have a connection with themselves.
    # Remove self connections, to keep only connected nodes which are different.
    edge1 = df_edge1[~(df_edge1[node]==df_edge1[node+"_2"])].dropna()[[node, node +"_2", column_edge]]
        
    # To avoid counting twice the connections (person 1 connected to person 2 and person 2 connected to person 1)
    # we force the first ID to be "lower" then ID_2
    edge1.drop(edge1.loc[edge1[node+"_2"]<edge1[node]].index.tolist(), inplace=True)

    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df=edge1, source=node, target=node + '_2', edge_attr=column_edge)

    G.add_nodes_from(nodes_for_adding=df[node].tolist())


    if column_edge1:


        df_edge2 = df[[node, column_edge1]].dropna(subset=[column_edge1]).drop_duplicates()

        df_edge2 = df_edge2.merge(
            df_edge2[[node, column_edge1]].rename(columns={node:node+"_2"}), 
            on=column_edge1
        )

        edge2 = df_edge2[~(df_edge2[node]==df_edge2[node+"_2"])].dropna()[[node, node+"_2", column_edge1]]

        edge2.drop(edge2.loc[edge2[node+"_2"]<edge2[node]].index.tolist(), inplace=True)

        # Create the connections in the graph
        links_attributes = {tuple(row[[node, node+"_2"]]): {column_edge1: row[column_edge1]} for i,row in edge2.iterrows()}

        # create the connection, without attribute.
        G.add_edges_from(links_attributes)
        # adds the attribute.
        nx.set_edge_attributes(G=G, values=links_attributes)


    if column_edge2:

        df_edge3 = df[[node, column_edge2]].dropna(subset=[column_edge2]).drop_duplicates()

        df_edge3 = df_edge3.merge(
                                  df_edge3[[node, column_edge2]].rename(columns={node:node+"_2"}), 
                                  on=column_edge2
                                  )


        edge3 = df_edge3[~(df_edge3[node]==df_edge3[node+"_2"])].dropna()[[node, node+"_2", column_edge2]]

        edge3.drop(edge3.loc[edge3[node+"_2"]<edge3[node]].index.tolist(), inplace=True)

        # Create the connections in the graph
        links_attributes2 = {tuple(row[[node, node+"_2"]]): {column_edge2: row[column_edge2]} for i,row in edge3.iterrows()}

        # create the connection, without attribute.
        G.add_edges_from(links_attributes2) 
        # adds the attribute.
        nx.set_edge_attributes(G=G, values=links_attributes2)
    
    return G
```

Calling the above function

```
GE3 = create_network(data, 'Quote ID', "Email", column_edge1="Phone", column_edge2="VIN")
```

Graph info

```
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 2441
Number of edges: 8374
Average degree:   6.8611
```

```
# import pyvis
from pyvis.network import Network

# # create vis network
net = Network(notebook=True, width=1000, height=600)
# load the networkx graph
net.from_nx(GE3)
# show
net.show("pyvis_example.html")
```

When I'm trying to export the graph using `pyvis`. I'm getting a
TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Below is the complete error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-b34699ea995d> in <module>()
     17 net.from_nx(GE3)
     18 # show
---> 19 net.show("pyvis_example.html")

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvis/network.py in show(self, name)
    474         check_html(name)
    475         if self.template is not None:
--> 476             return self.write_html(name, notebook=True)
    477         else:
    478             self.write_html(name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvis/network.py in write_html(self, name, notebook)
    457                                     bgcolor=self.bgcolor,
    458                                     conf=self.conf,
--> 459                                     tooltip_link=use_link_template)
    460 
    461         with open(name, "w+") as out:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py in render(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1088             return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))
   1089         except Exception:
-> 1090             self.environment.handle_exception()
   1091 
   1092     def render_async(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py in handle_exception(self, source)
    830         from .debug import rewrite_traceback_stack
    831 
--> 832         reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
    833 
    834     def join_path(self, template, parent):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     26     def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
     27         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
---> 28             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     29         raise value
     30 

<template> in top-level template code()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2/filters.py in do_tojson(eval_ctx, value, indent)
   1258         options = dict(options)
   1259         options["indent"] = indent
-> 1260     return htmlsafe_json_dumps(value, dumper=dumper, **options)
   1261 
   1262 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py in htmlsafe_json_dumps(obj, dumper, **kwargs)
    617         dumper = json.dumps
    618     rv = (
--> 619         dumper(obj, **kwargs)
    620         .replace(u"<", u"\\u003c")
    621         .replace(u">", u"\\u003e")

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

I think the error is from the Graph network but I'm not sure where exactly is this happening and how to fix this....

Can anyone shed some light to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your node indices are `int` types and not `int64` or `int32`. Same would go for your edge construction. I would recommend checking the `type` of your `df[node]` pandas series.

Comment: how to convert int64 or int32 to int?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to int all variables you know are int. In python, you can cast in this way: **int(**int64var**)**.

If you don't want to cast all variables, you can debug your code and see variable per variable, if the variable type is correct.

Comment: I tried with `int()`, I'm getting the same error

Comment: Look at very well for every var that is need to be casted.